# Unable to translate text to other language inside cell or some table in pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

Unable to translate text to german inside cell or some table in pptx. However the simple text in slides are getting translated.

My input pptx looks like below:
[image]

Getting output like below: Hello World and so on not getting translated..

[image]

code I am using like below:

```
prs = Presentation('old.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides: 
    for shape in slide.shapes: 
        if not shape.has_text_frame: 
            continue
        text_frame = shape.text_frame
        text_frame.text=translator.translate(text_frame.text,dest='de').text



prs.save('new.pptx')
```

Can the above code be tweaked so that the translation can be done for all of inside pptx ?
I can understand its looking for text frame but any chance to tweak this to work ?
If I remove below from the above code will get the error ...

```
   if not shape.has_text_frame: 
            continue
```

*AttributeError: 'Picture' object has no attribute 'text_frame'*

I went through the python-pptx docs and found there are functions for char , table , pictures etc but unable to figure out how to pass this for translation so that text inside it can be translated ..
Reference Link - https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate the cells of any tables separately, something like this:

```
def iter_cells(table):
    """Generate each cell in *table*, left-to-right, top-to-bottom."""
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            yield cell

def translate_table(table):
    for cell in iter_cells(table):
        text_frame = cell.text_frame
        text_frame.text = translator.translate(text_frame.text, dest='de').text

for shape in slide.shapes:
    if shape.has_table:
        translate_table(shape.table)
    if not shape.has_text_frame:
        continue
    ...
```

Note that a table is not itself a shape. Rather it is contained by a `GraphicFrame` shape.

On the pictures question, not all shapes can contain text. A picture shape is one of those, which is why it must be skipped before trying to access the `TextFrame` object it does not (and cannot) have.